# Only load size of images / attributes but not the actual content

Tags: javascript, plugins

I am trying to write a chrome plugin so I can use some websites that includes a lot of images I dont care about that are problematic to load seeing as my internet connection is poor.

As such, is it possible to stop loading images but just load white boxes instead, with the exact same size, attributed links etc.? I am a bit unsure where to even start on this, as I tried to just .display = None, but that does not help me loading the website when my connection is bad.

Reason why I want to load something is because if all the images etc just disappear the website layout basically goes down the drain and I can't scroll around on it.

Comment: This will prevent images loading: $(document).ready( function() { $("img").removeAttr("src"); } );  Used with tampler monkey https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en you may be able to prevent images from loading.

Comment: Couple of follow up questions: 1. How do I put that into a regular chrome plugin JS 2 Does this reprent images from loading or just appearing 3. Is it possible to take the image attributes first like size etc.?

Comment: It should prevent loading and your on your own with the Chrome plugin. You'd be better off using tamper monkey.